Search Widget default source layer in Experience Builder
I am trying to build my Search Widget in Experience Builder. I need to have multiple search source layers but I want 1 specific layer to be the default. Every time I try my map, I have to choose the dropdown arrow, unselect all and choose which layer I want to search. If I don't, the search takes FOREVER. Is there any way to make a "default"?
